# What is the relationship between a 2d Cartesian coordinate grid and a matrix of arrays?

Tags: arrays, matrix

I am working with a complex problem that involves an array matrix. Usually I think of matrices as having a row index and a column index.

```
matrix[row][column]
```

But for this particular problem I think it would be more useful to think of it in the context of Cartesian coordinates. When doing this though I noticed there are a few distinct issues such that matrix indices can only be positive integers as opposed to Cartesian coordinates which can span in any direction. I also find myself slightly confused as to how x and y as indices would map to rows and columns as indices.

What is the relationship between a 2d Cartesian coordinate grid and a matrix of arrays?

Comment: The relationships are whatever you define them to be. If you want `matrix[1][1]` to represent point `(1,1)`, then cool. You could also define it to be point `(-5,-5)`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a major concern of yours is how you would represent a Cartesian coordinate system using a Java two dimensional array.  The confusing part of this is how to deal with negative coordinates since Java arrays can only be indexed by positive numbers.  Here is a class `CartesianGrid` which contains a 2D array of integers.  The array can be initialized with any range of Cartesian coordinates.  The getter and setter offset negative coordinates to map to the range of the array which Java expects.

```
public class CartesianArray {
    private int[][] grid;
    private int minX, minY;
    private int sizeX, sizeY;

    public CartesianArray(int minX, int minY, int maxX, int maxY) {
        this.minX = minX;
        this.minY = minY;
        sizeX = maxX - minX + 1;
        sizeY = maxY - minY + 1;
        grid = new int[sizeX][sizeY];
    }

    public void setPoint(int xCart, int yCart, int value) {
        int x = xCart - xMin; // offset negative x value
        int y = yCart - yMin; // offset negative y value

        // check for out of bounds coordinates
        if (x < 0 || x >= sizeX || y < 0 || y >= sizeY) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot set a point outside the grid.");
        } else {
            grid[x][y] = value;
        }
    }

    public int getPoint(int xCart, int yCart) {
        int x = xCart - xMin; // offset negative x value
        int y = yCart - yMin; // offset negative y value

        if (x < 0 || x >= sizeX || y < 0 || y >= sizeY) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot get a point outside the grid.");
        } else {
            return grid[x][y];
        }
    }
}
```